# Theano Import Error, python 3.6 windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, theano

I'm trying to import `theano` and I'm getting an import error.

I've seen common issues with `theano` relate to not having `g++`, `mingw`, or `libpython` installed. I can confirm I have all three installed. `g++ 4.7.0`, `mingw 4.7`, `libpython 2.1`, and `theano 1.0.1`.

Any suggestions on what to chase down next? I'm a little stumped.

When I run a simple python (3.6) file trying to import theano I get the following:

```
You can find the C code in this temporary file: C:\Users\CAVEJO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\theano_compilation_error_1b3hfusl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cave Johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 75, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cave Johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 92, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cave Johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Projects\Pandas\housing_prices.py", line 4, in <module>
    import theano
  File "C:\Users\Cave Johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (
  File "C:\Users\Cave Johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from theano.compile.mode import *
  File "C:\Users\Cave Johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 11, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "C:\Users\Cave Johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 673, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c
  File "C:\Users\Cave Johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in <module>
    preargs=args)
  File "C:\Users\Cave Johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2359, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): The system cannot find the path specified.
```

.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and it came down to missing dependencies.

This seemed to be the key for me:

```
conda install numpy scipy mkl-service libpython m2w64-toolchain
conda install -c conda-forge blas
```

See https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/6532 or more details.